# Ruby + Testunit + ci_reporter: No xml output

Tags: ruby, testunit

I have the following Rakefile:

```
require 'rake'

gem 'ci_reporter'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'

task :test do
  ruby 'signup.rb'
end
```

And the following file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'

class SignupTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_signup
        assert true
    end
end
```

When i run "rake ci:setup:testunit test" i get:

```
rm -rf test/reports
/Users/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby signup.rb
Run options: 

# Running tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.000820s, 1219.5122 tests/s, 1219.5122 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Seems like it should have generated some kind of content in test/reports but this directory does not exist.

Any ideas of what i should do?

Comment: @Trejkaz that's a link to this question :)

Comment: True. I thought I had copied a link to the issue someone posted about it.  My bad... now I can't find the original either. :(

Comment: @Fernando Have you fixed this issue?  I met same issue with you

Comment: @Dan nope. Couldn't make it work. I ended up using this gem https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter

Comment: @Fernando you linked to the gem that was giving you trouble. Was that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the require lines to:

```
gem 'ci_reporter'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit_loader'
```

(I had a similar issue with MiniTest where the documentation said to require minitest but I discovered that there was a minitest_loader and requiring that worked!)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same probleme. 
Try this :

- Add the following requires to your test.rb : `require 'test/unit'`

  `require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit_loader'` 
  `gem 'test-unit'`
- Add the following require to your rakefile.rb : `require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'  #http://juretta.com/log/2008/11/11/hudson_test_drive_part_1_rails/`
- Execute with the cmd : `rake CI_REPORTS=reports test`

Hope this will help you, it worked for me.